# pass php variable to HTML input

Tags: javascript, php, html

My issue is that I want to pass som php-variables to HTML input.

```
echo $ManuellTagnavnMain;
for ($n = 0; $n < 6; $n++) {
  print_r(++$ManuellTagnavnMain.PHP_EOL);
}
```

I would like to pass all of the values to HTML input(s). 
How is this done?

Comment: This page shows simple examples of values embedded in HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp

Comment: No, the link you are referring to doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well the question isn't very clear, to be fair...

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will try to improve till next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

echo $ManuellTagnavnMain;
for ($n = 0; $n < 6; $n++) { ?>

Input: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $n; ?>"/>

<?php
  print_r(++$ManuellTagnavnMain.PHP_EOL);
}
?>
```

You can set Php values into html elements like this

Comment: Thank you! It worked as I wanted it to, as I replaced $n with $ManuellTagnavnMain in value="<?php echo $n; ?>"/>

Comment: @KamalanRashasingham : Yu can accept and upvote if it helped :)

Comment: How do I do that? It says I dont have enough reputation.